# Ejecutar script desde varios elementos con el mismo nombre

Tags: javascript, html5

Buenas trades tengo varios elementos  `<img class="img-producto">` y una función javascript en la cual busco con los eventos `'mouseover'`y `'mouseout'` es que al pasar por las imagenes que estan en `<img class="img-producto">` se cambie de tamaño de imagen. El problema es que no se como hacerlo funcionar ya que como lo mencione anteriormente todos estan con el `<img class="img-producto">`

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
        <img  src="images/lentera.png" class="img-producto" id="img-product" style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="160" height="180">
        <h2>Leche Entera</h2>
        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <img  class="img-producto" id="img-product" style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);" src="images/lsemidescremada.png" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="160" height="180">
        <h2>Leche Pasteurizada Semidescremada</h2>
        <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <img class="img-producto"  id="img-product" style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);" src="images/lentera.png" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="160" height="180">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('img-producto');
alert(x.length);
x.addEventListener('mouseover', productoHover );
x.addEventListener('mouseout', productoOut );
  function productoHover(){

    x.style.transform = "matrix(1.1, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0)";
}
function productoOut(){
    x.style.transform = "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)";
}
</script>
```

Agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo primero que debes hacer es agregar los eventos a cada uno de los elementos, como son varios debes agregarlo uno por uno, esto lo consigues con un ciclo `for`, luego por medio de `this` puedes ejecutar los eventos en el elemento con el cual el usuario esta interactuando ignorando los demás

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('img-producto');

for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
  x[i].addEventListener('mouseover', productoHover);
  x[i].addEventListener('mouseout', productoOut);
}

function productoHover(){
    this.style.transform = "matrix(1.1, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0)";
}

function productoOut(){
    this.style.transform = "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)";
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <img  src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/3382/f/2008/336/6/b/lentera_by_nangz.jpg" class="img-producto" id="img-product" style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="160" height="180">
  <h2>Leche Entera</h2>
  <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
</div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <img  class="img-producto" id="img-product" style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);" src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/3382/f/2008/336/6/b/lentera_by_nangz.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="160" height="180">
  <h2>Leche Pasteurizada Semidescremada</h2>
  <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
</div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <img class="img-producto"  id="img-product" style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);" src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/3382/f/2008/336/6/b/lentera_by_nangz.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="160" height="180">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, justo lo que necesitaba